# Drupal 7 Views Contextual Filter Override Title, but Make Singular

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms, views

I have been able to setup a view that uses contextual filters that are taxonomy terms.  The terms are categories and as such are written in the plural form, for example, "Posters" or "Flyers".  However, when I overwrite the titles by using the %1 override I want it to print out "Poster Templates" instead of "Posters Templates".

Here is my current configuration:
[image: Views contextual filters singular]

Comment: is your view of fields??? `(Show: Fields | Settings)`